# selectize.js не работает поиск

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно сделать что бы при нажатии на selectize всегда можно было печатать и находить нужный вариант, но так не работает. При выборе варианта дальнейший поиск недоступен.
Я гн могу удалить выбранный вариант и искать снова. Как это сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы решили эту проблему?
....................................

Comment: Да, решил, обновил библиотеку на последнюю версию